# Why i am getting null values when i call to procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
delimiter $$
create procedure fp10 ( in d varchar(30),out di int)
begin
select id into di from a1 where department  = d;
end $$
delimiter ;

 call fp10('IT',@di);
 select @di;
```